# Match multiple properties on the same nested document in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql

I'm trying to accomplish what boils down to a boolean `AND` on nested documents in ElasticSearch. Let's say I have the following two documents.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "secondLevels": [
        {
            "thirdLevels": [
                {
                    "isActive": true,
                    "user": "anotheruser@domain.com"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "thirdLevels": [
                {
                    "isActive": false,
                    "user": "user@domain.com"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
{
    "id": 2,
    "secondLevels": [
        {
            "thirdLevels": [
                {
                    "isActive": true,
                    "user": "user@domain.com"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In this case, I want to only match documents (in this case ID: 2) that have a nested document with both `isActive: true` AND `user: user@domain.com`.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "secondLevels.thirdLevels",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                    {
                                        "term": {
                                            "secondLevels.thirdLevels.isActive": true
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "term": {
                                            "secondLevels.thirdLevels.user": "user@domain.com"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

However, what seems to be happening is that my query turns up both documents because the first document has one `thirdLevel` that has `isActive: true` and another `thirdLevel` that has the appropriate user.

Is there any way to enforce this strictly at query/filter time or do I have to do this in a script?

Comment: What version of elastic are you using? I've created an index and tested your query locally and I only return the user with id = 2. The reason I ask, I believe the "must" grouping should be defaulting to AND unless you're perhaps somehow defaulting to OR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With nested-objects and nested-query, you have made most of the way.

All you have to do now is to add the [inner hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html) flag and also use [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html) for move entire `secondLevels` documents out of the way:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "secondLevels.thirdLevels",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "secondLevels.thirdLevels.isActive": true
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "secondLevels.thirdLevels.user": "user@domain.com"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "inner_hits": {
              "size": 100
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```